# Black box showing up on form, how do I get rid of it

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF, I've been working in WINFORMS for quite some time. When I create a new window, I get this black box showing up at the top center of the screen.

[image]

What is this and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: I believe this is showing up only when you run in visual studio 2017

Comment: thank you all! I didnt know what it was to search on the option so now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio debug feature. Unselect the "Show runtime tools in application" button in the Live Visual Tree pane in Visual Studio.

[image]